# How to add checkboxes dynamically in both column header and rows in a datagrid?

Tags: javascript, angular, html, angular-reactive-forms

I want to add checkboxes in header (Before - Monday, Tuesday..) and rows dynamically in a datagrid, using angular reactive forms.[image: Design]

The `Week1, Week2..` values are looped through an array of

```
weeks = ['Week1','Week2','Week3','Week4']
```

Similarly, the column headers is also looped through another array of days.

Need to know some way using `FormArray` of reactive forms to implemement the checkboxes in both header of columns and all the rows.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you want to structure your data, and how the "form array" should look like

Comment: form: FormGroup;
  weeks = [
    { name: 'Week 1' },
    { name: 'Week 2' },
    { name: 'Week 3' },
    { name: 'Week 4' }
  ];

Comment: Pretty unclear,  and the days ? What do you want to do when you have finish to select everything ?

Comment: @xrobert35                                                                                                    
constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {let controls =this.weeks.map(c => new FormControl(false));
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({weeks: new FormArray(controls) });}          On select everything , the values will be saved to a payload object which will then be sent for HTTP POST request.

Comment: the datagrid is a component of your own or an external one ?

Comment: Ext. Clarity's <clr-datagrid><clr-dg-column></clr-dg-column><clr-dg-column *ngFor="let day of days"><input [attr.id]="product" type="checkbox"><label [attr.for]="product">{{ product }}</label></clr-dg-column><clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let week of weeks;let indexForWeek = index" [clrDgItem]="week"><clr-dg-cell class="col-lg-3"><div>{{ week }}</div></clr-dg-cell><clr-dg-cell* ngFor="let day of days;let indexForDay = index"><input type="checkbox" [attr.id]="'day-'+indexForWeek+indexForDay"><label [attr.for]="'day'+indexForWeek+indexForDay"></label></clr-dg-cell></clr-dg-row></clr-datagrid>

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible way to do what I think you want to do :

1 - Generate the FormGroup

```
  days = ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S', 'S'];
  weeks = ['Week1', 'Week2', 'Week3'];
  formGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      weeks: this.fb.array(this.initFormDatas())
    });
    console.log(this.formGroup);
  }

  initFormDatas() {
    const groups = [];
    this.weeks.forEach((week) => {
      groups.push(this.fb.array(this.initDaysFormControls(week)));
    });
    return groups;
  }

  initDaysFormControls(week) {
    const controls = [];
    this.days.forEach((days) => {
      controls.push(new FormControl());
    });
    return controls;
  }
```

A simplified HTML that you could easily adapt : 
onWeekSelected is a simple function allowing you to select or unselect every checkbox of a column

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th *ngFor="let day of days">
        <input type="checkbox" (change)="onWeekSelected($event)" /> {{ day }}
      </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody formArrayName="weeks">
      <tr *ngFor="let week of weeks; let weekIndex=index">
        <td> {{ week }} </td>
        <ng-container [formArrayName]="weekIndex">
          <td *ngFor="let day of days; let dayIndex=index">
            <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="dayIndex" />
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

result when submitting :

```
  submitForm() {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.formGroup.value));
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Following your approach, In initDaysFormControls function, the argument week is not being used (what's the correction required?). I have initialized the form group in the constructor instead of ngOnInit, so how to access this.weeks inside initFormDatas(), it should be accessed like this.form.get('weeks'), but forEach cannot be applicable on it as it is an abstract form control. Can we have days also as form array? Note: Both the days and weeks arrays values are coming from api, so these values are being pushed to days and weeks array after some manipulation in a separate function on api data.

Comment: The initFormDaysFormControls take a "week" as parameter cause when you will be  in "editing" mode, you will need the week the initialize the formControl (true ou false if the day is selected or not)

Comment: init in the constructor or in the ngOnInit change nothing to the actual code,  this.weeks  will be accessible in both way. I prefere ngOnInit cause it's part of the angular component lifecycle.  
** Can we have days as form array  ? **. It's already the case, no ?  
It's not a problem that your data come from an API,  you should resolve them in a "resolver" (part of the "Router" specification)